# Can I have a sbt multiproject inside another multiproject?

Tags: scala, sbt

That seems not to work. The main reason why I want that is to share common settings like 'publishTo' or 'credentials' among multiple multiprojects.

Having a project structure like this

```
root
  |--L1
      |--L2
```

I would like to define settings in L1 and use them in L2 as well as defining settings in root and using them in L1 and L2.

Comment: The answer is yes, but I only know that it's possible. My coworker set one up to unify some formerly disparate but interrelated projects we have. I'll try to get him to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you can share settings at the build level with any subproject, by specifying `in ThisBuild` in the `build.sbt` file at the root of the project, as mentioned in http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#sharing-settings

But that only works to share a value among all projects.

In your case, if you have defined your projects as following in `Build.scala`

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "root",
                            base = file("."))

    lazy val L1 = Project(id = "L1",
                           base = file("L1"))

    lazy val L2 = Project(id = "L2",
                           base = file("L1/L2"))
}
```

If you want to reuse a key (e.g `publishTo`) you have defined in `L1` in `L2`, you'll write the following line in `L2` `build.sbt`

```
publishTo <<= publishTo in L1
```

You can use the `inspect` command in sbt to check-out key values and how they are set.

```
> projects
[info] In file:/Users/leo/src/project0/
[info]     L1
[info]     L2
[info]   * root
> project L2
[info] Set current project to L2 (in build file:/Users/leo/src/project0/)
> inspect publish-to
[info] Setting: scala.Option[sbt.Resolver] = Some(Repo1: https://repo1.org)
[info] Description:
[info]  The resolver to publish to.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/leo/src/project0/}L2/*:publish-to
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/leo/src/project0/L1/L2/build.sbt:1
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  L1/*:publish-to
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  L2/*:publish-configuration
[info]  L2/*:other-resolvers
[info] Delegates:
[info]  L2/*:publish-to
[info]  {.}/*:publish-to
[info]  */*:publish-to
[info] Related:
[info]  L1/*:publish-to
[info]  */*:publish-to
[info]  {.}/*:publish-to
>
```

Comment: It seems only be possible to share settings from the root project. If I have a three level project, all subprojects can share settings from the root level.

Comment: As a conclusion, I would say SBT does not really support more than one level of hierarchy. Even if you put modules in subdirectories of other modules, it does not mean that there is any connection between these modules.